# intellij: database tools tools access issue

Tags: intellij-idea

On IntelliJ 2020.3.2 Ultimate, I started getting the 'Unable to unlock keychain' issue when using Database tools plugin on Mac OS (Big Sur), not been a problem before.

I uninstalled the Database tools plugin and reinstalled it.

It didn't fix.
Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-228926

Comment: After restart mac book, the issue is resolved on my local pc.